# Mysql 4.x LOAD DATA FROM MASTER; slave

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a scenario where there are multiple mysql 4.x servers.  These databases were supposed to be replicating to another server.  After checking things out on a slave it appears that this slave has not replicated any databases in some time.

Some of these databases are > 4G in size and one is 43G(which resides on another server).  Has anyone out there replicated databases without creating a snapshot to copy over to a slave?  I cannot shutdown the master server because of the downtime.   It will probably take over an hour and 40 minutes to create a snapshot.  So this is out of the question.

I was going to perform a load data from master on the slave to pull everything from scratch.  Any idea how long this will take on databases ranging from 1-4G and the 43G database will be for another day.   All of the tables on the master are myIsam so I don't think I will have a problem with the load from master method.

What are the best methods on the slave to clean things up or reset things so I can just start from a clean slate?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a snapshot to start replication.  Snapshots require either the database to be locked (at least) read-only. So you can have a consistent place to start from.

Downtime is a necessary thing, customers usually understand it as long as it doesn't happen too often.